# Redirect all pages to single page on SAME domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are versions of this question already posted but i cannot get their suggestions to work.

Here is what i have already in my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ index.php 
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
```

and here is what i tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ index.php 
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.trainingthemlive.co.uk/maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

No luck, just completely fails. I'd like www.trainingthemlive.co.uk to go to www.trainingthemlive.co.uk/maintenance

It's also worth noting that the maintenance.php page is in the root folder and def exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure *not* to redirect the maintenance page, and you probably want it before your other rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^/?(maintenance\.php|.*\.css|.*\.js)$ http://www.trainingthemlive.co.uk/maintenance.php [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ index.php 
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
```

Comment: Annoyingly this breaks my css and js files. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AndyHolmes then you need to exclude those too (since a css file is *also a page*), see the added exclusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single rule:

```
RewriteRule !^maintenance /maintenance [L,NC,R]
```

This will redirect all pages on your domain to `/maintenance`

Comment: Make sure to place this rule **before all other existing rules**